# Google Spreadsheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem creating a formula for my sheets. I want Google Spreadsheets to put either *Yes* or *No* in a specific cell depending on the values in other cell. In other words I want it to put *Yes* when all the cells between `B` and `P` have values and put *No* when cells between `B` and `P` are not complete, even one empty cell is not acceptable.

How can I create such a formula?

Comment: What now, Google docs or Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell A2: `=IF(COUNTIF(B2:P2,"<>")=COLUMNS(B2:P2),"Yes","No")` fill down to get it into the rows below.